# Exported property gets hidden in dynamic import using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5, filesaver.js, dynamic-import

In the latest webpack version (5+) when i try to use exported content of dynamic loaded module i can't see its property (got undefined) - the only way is to use `module.default.method` instead of `module.method`. I noticed that using `file-saver` library, but also reproduced it with simple module - i recreated the way `saveAs` function is exported in file-saver.
Here is the problematic repo:
https://github.com/snffquake/webpack_demo

With webpack 5+ both `console.log`s return `undefined`s and with webpack 4 i get functions as expected. I can't see any breaking changes in the webpack changelog that could cause that. Also, I am not sure if `file-saver` exports function in the right way, however it worked differently in the previous webpack versions.
So the question is, is the correct behavior or am i doing something wrong?